# New Root API for ReactDOM using createRoot() instead of render()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I received a console warning that render is deprecated and running React 17 not React 18. Additionally, redux deprecated createStore in favor of configureStore. How would I implement the new createRoot and configureStore?

```
const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per our documentation at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#store-setup , your `createStore` call can be replaced with:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
})
```

(Yes, that's it!  It did the `compose` and `applyMiddleware(thunk)` steps for you.)

Note that the `reducers` variable can also probably be skipped by passing those slice reducers directly to `configureStore`:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    users: usersReducer,
    posts: postsReducer,
    // etc

  }
})
```

For `createRoot`, per the React 18 upgrade guide at https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis , switch to:

```js
const reactRoot = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

reactRoot.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
)
```